# Premium / Free Versions of App using Libraries?

Tags: android

I've read up on and have a pretty good understanding of Library projects in Eclipse, but there's one functionality of it I don't understand. I'd like to declare one of my Apps as a library project and use it to create a premium, paid app and a free, ad-supported version. I've heard that this is possible, but I'm still not sure exactly how I'd make it work.

My experience with Libraries is to use them to provide frameworks for other Apps to utilize. That's the area I'm having trouble figuring out; in essence, I wouldn't be adding anything to the project, but modifying some of the layout files to add an ad banner view, so I'm not sure how to make a project overwrite a Library file, or if that's even the right thing to do.

Can anyone please give any ideas of how I might achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications can override library resources, so in the simple case, you can create a new version of your layout but with an added ad on the top or bottom. Additionally you could probably do some subclassing or dependency injection to manipulate navigation flows for interstitials. Instead of launching what would be the "next" activity in your paid version directly, if you want to have an interstitial in your ad version, you can get an intent from some navigation manager class, the implementation of which gives you a different intent in your ad version vs. paid version.

Comment: You say they "can" override them...is there anything special I need to do, or will the compiler just say "Okay, I see main.xml in the Library but there's a main.xml in the other project, so I'll use the second one"?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html): "In cases where a resource ID is defined in both the application and the library, the tools ensure that the resource declared in the application gets priority and that the resource in the library project is not compiled into the application .apk"